# What's considered (in)appropriate use of request.env in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, env

My understanding is that request.env stores info about user's or server's environment. Looking at a piece of ActionDispatch [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5359262695b491422b18c565567e16ad50f6155e/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L74) I see it storing an exception, and it made me wonder if this is appropriate?

That leads me to a more general question of what would be considered some (in)appropriate uses of using request.env?

Comment: love how you highlighted a specific line.. never seen that before!

Answer (score 0):

here is a usefull source that you can take a look into.

http://blogofchirag.blogspot.com/2008/09/variables-in-request-env-ruby-on-rails.html